# Joint PDF with parameter $N\in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, probability, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, density-function

> Let $$f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}, (x,y) \mapsto 
> \
>      f(x,y)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} N\cdot \mathrm{e}^{-\alpha x-\beta y}, & x\ge 0, y \ge 0\\
>          0, & \text{else}\end{array}\right. .
>   $$
>   with $\alpha, \beta >0, N\in \mathbb{R}$.
>
> For which $N$, f is a joint PDF?

Okay, I know the characteristics of a joint PDF:
$$(1) \int_{\mathbb{R}^2}f(x,y)dxdy=1$$
$$(2)\quad f(x,y)\ge 0$$

The second assumption is true for $N>0$. 
I've tried to get the right $N$ so that the integral is $1$ but I had problems with the integration respect to $x$ *and* $y$.

Any hints?
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We define f on $\mathbb{R^2}$ such that $$f(x,y)=N e^{-\alpha x-\beta y}1_{x\geq0}1_{y\geq0}$$

$f$ must be positive, therefore we choose $N>0$.

We apply Tonelli's theorem :

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}f(x,y)dxdy=N\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-\alpha x}1_{x\geq0}dx\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-\beta y}1_{y\geq0}dy$$

We define the integrale $I(u)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-u y}1_{y\geq0}dy$ where $u>0$.

Clearly, we have 
$$I(u)=\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{-u y}dy}=\left[-\frac{e^{-uy}}{u}\right]_{0}^{\infty}=\frac{1}{u}$$

Using this result we have that 
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}f(x,y)dxdy=NI(\alpha)I(\beta)=\frac{N}{\alpha \beta}$$

We want this integral to be equal to $1$, thus, $N=\alpha \beta$

Comment: It is a consequence of the Tonelli's theorem, you can write

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}f(x,y)dxdy=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x,y)dx\right)dy=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x,y)dy\right)dx$$

Comment: Thanks! One additional question: How I can evaluate $\mathbb{E}[X]$ without $Y$, if I have the distribution function?

Comment: $$E(X)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}xf(x,y)dxdy=\int_{\mathbb{R}}x \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x,y)dy\right)dx$$.

You must now calculate 
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x,y)dy$$